# How to export all data on ag grid angular even a filter is applied?

Tags: angular, ag-grid, angular12

I implemented ag-grid on a project and I want to export all data listed on ag-grid table.

Issue : If I apply a filter and export the csv from ag-grid, then the exported file contains just filtred data.

Wanted : Export all data even a filter is applied.

I searched on the official documentation on ag-grid and I didn't find anything that can helps me.

Thank you.

**Template :**

```
<div align="end">
  <button mat-stroked-button color="primary" (click)="onBtnExport()">TELECHARGER</button>
  <button mat-flat-button color="primary" (click)="onCreateProtocole()">CREER PROTOCOLE</button>
</div>
<div>
  <ag-grid-angular
    style="width: 100%; height: 500px"
    class="ag-theme-material ag-theme-rgo"
    [rowData]="rowData"
    [columnDefs]="columnDefs"
    [defaultColDef]="defaultColDef"
    rowSelection="multiple"
    [floatingFilter]="true"
    [pagination]="true"
    (firstDataRendered)="onFirstDataRendered($event)"
    (gridReady)="onGridReady($event)"
    (rowClicked)="onRowClicked($event)"
  >
  </ag-grid-angular>
</div>
```

**TS**

```
   columnDefs: ColDef[] = [
    { headerName: 'Libéllé protocole', field: 'libelleProtocole', filter: 'agTextColumnFilter', suppressMenu: true },
    { headerName: 'Nb FD Utilisatrices', field: 'nbFdUtilisatrices', filter: 'agTextColumnFilter', suppressMenu: true },
    { headerName: 'Date de création',
      field: 'dateCreationProtocole',
      filter: 'agDateColumnFilter',
      suppressMenu: true,
      valueGetter: (params) => this.datePipe.transform(params.data.dateCreationProtocole, 'dd/MM/yyyy')
    },
    { headerName: 'Date de modification', field: 'dateModificationProtocole', filter: 'agDateColumnFilter', suppressMenu: true,
      valueGetter: (params) => this.datePipe.transform(params.data.dateModificationProtocole, 'dd/MM/yyyy')},
    { headerName: 'Protocole invalide', field: 'protocoleInvalide', filter: 'agTextColumnFilter', suppressMenu: true,
      valueGetter(params) {
        return params.data.protocoleInvalide ? '-' : 'Invalide';
      },
    }
  ];
  rowData: any;
  defaultColDef: any;
  private gridApi: any;
  private gridColumnApi: any;

  constructor(private dialog: MatDialog,
              private protocoleService: ProtocoleService,
              @Inject(LOCALE_ID) private locale: string,
              private datePipe: DatePipe) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.defaultColDef = {
      flex: 1,
      minWidth: 150,
      filter: true,
      sortable: true,
      floatingFilter: true,
    };
  }
  onFirstDataRendered(params: any): void {
    params.api.sizeColumnsToFit();
  }

  onGridReady(params: any): void {
    this.gridApi = params.api;
    this.gridColumnApi = params.columnApi;
  }

  onBtnExport(): void {
    const params = {
      fileName: "REMI_PROTOCOLES.csv"
    };
    this.gridApi.exportDataAsCsv(params)
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can override this and export all rows instead of only the filtered rows by setting the exportedRows param to ‘all’.

```
 this.gridApi.exportDataAsExcel({
      exportedRows: 'all',
    });
```

Refer [this](https://www.ag-grid.com/react-data-grid/excel-export-rows/) document for more

Answer (score 0):

*AG-Grid* doesn't provide any API as of yet to export all the data even if a filter is applied.

This [issue](https://github.com/ag-grid/ag-grid/issues/1499) has already been reported on *ag-grid's* official GitHub repository.

[Here](https://github.com/ag-grid/ag-grid/issues/1499#issuecomment-430170729) is an ugly but working patch for this issue, You can try it until *ag-grid* support this functionality via an API method.